# Why use /home instead of /var?

Tags: linux, unix, configuration

I have seen many tutorials and real life configurations using `/home` to keep logs or even websites instead of leaving things in `/var/logs` or `/var/www`.

Why?

Comment: Explain the downvote, this configuration with /home is not recommandable but it's seen in the wild, is my question not relevant?

Comment: http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml Just so the official standards are mentionned in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it doesn't comply with most (any?) standards, the reason many do it is because of filesystem sizes.  Most users store their personal files in `/home` because hey...  it's their home directory.  Because of that, the most storage is allocated to `/home`.  It's generally considered bad practice to have `/home` on the same FS as `/` because if `/home` fills up because of a standard user, and everybody knows the average user isn't paying attention to that, then they've just potentially crippled the entire server.

Now, since the next filesystem to potentially use lots of space is `/var`, usually because of `/var/log` and/or `/var/www`, `/var` is usually ALSO kept on its own filesystem.  Those companies in the world with smaller cash flow (or individuals in Mom's basement) will consolidate drive space, most frequently by using `/home` and moving httpd's `DocumentRoot` over to `/home` somewhere.

The company I work for handles it properly.  My personal machine has `/var/www` in its standard location, but it's just a symlink over to `/home/varwww`, where the larger filesystem lives, so while the hierarchy standard is mostly adhered to, I deviate from it for other, more practical, reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Because those tutorials are meant for non-productions environments, or for amateur developers and/or sysadmins, or for proof-of-concept quick-and-dirty installations.

If you mean to maintain a system in a long-term fashion, adhere to standards and best practices, i.e., don't use `/home` to serve web content or to keep logs.

Comment: I would just add that on most UNIX (not Linux) it's generally discouraged to store data such as websites in `/var` (which is primarily for system logs and process info). Do what makes sense for your environment, which may be to just use defaults for a small system, but for larger systems, it may be preferable to have a completely independent mount for web/log data. (possibly even storage provided by a NAS or SAN - although I generally wouldn't advise actively logging to remote mounts).

Comment: Amateur sysadmins are everywhere then, even in big hosting companies as I've seen this in a lot of procedures at 2 different companies. IMHO it wasn't a good practice but I figured there might be a valid reason to use /home.

Comment: None that I can think of. And no, being a "big" company does not ensure best practices are in place.

Comment: I second dawud's statement: Being a "big" company most definitely does not ensure that.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I really see this setup is on a shared server, such as a shell host or web host. Users are `chroot`ed to their home directory and have a public_html folder that the web server deamon looks at for their website.